# Make Enter/Return key submit a form and execute function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple form verification system for my website - the Login() function - and want the small aesthetic of allowing users to just press enter to submit a form. However, I have two separate forms - both using the same tag attributes - but one and the other doesn't. What's wrong?

**Working Code:**

```js
function Login() {

  var id = document.login.id.value;

  location.href = "users/" + id + ".html"

}
```

```html
<form name="login" method="get" onsubmit="return Login();">
  <input type="password" maxlength="7" name="id" id="id" placeholder="Session ID">
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Join" onClick="Login()">
  <a href="index.html"><button>Cancel</button></a>
</form>
```

**Broken Code:**

```js
function Login() {
  var done = 0;
  var username = document.login.username.value;
  username = username.toLowerCase();
  var password = document.login.password.value;

  if (username == "user1" && password == "password1") {
    window.location = "../account/user1/index.html";
    done = 1;
  }

  if (username == "user2" && password == "password2") {
    window.location = "../account/user2/index.html";
    done = 1;
  }
  if (username == "user3" && password == "password3") {
    window.location = "../account/user3/index.html";
    done = 1;
  }

  if (done == 0) {
    alert("Incorrect username/password.")
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="login" method="get" onsubmit="return Login();">
  Username:<input type="text" name="username">
  <br /> Password:
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="Login()">
  <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

Comment: You have 4 `if`'s try this:  `if`... `else if`... `else if` ... `else`

Comment: Btw, this is O(n1) for user checking...it's bad approach to build auth validation

Comment: It's not necessarily the security I'm working about, I just need to make the form's submission system respond to the press of the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the browser or web client you are using knows what button to press on submit, you should use:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onClick="Login()">
```

instead of

```
<input type="button" value="Login" onClick="Login()">
```

(Note the type attribute difference).

Comment: This doesn't execute the function, it adds ?username=&password= to the end the url.

Comment: Replace "return Login();" with "Login()" within the form label. Also remove the attribute "onClick="Login()" from the submit button, since you are not using it when pressing enter. Make sure you are calling the js file as well. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Actually, the ?username=&password= you see at the end of the URL is because you're sending the form data with the GET method. Using POST method will not add these attributes to the URL.